# Is it possible to use Laravel Passport authentication with web other then API?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6.2

Is it possible to use `Laravel Passport` with web page authentication? I have a larvel project which is using both API and WEB sides. I am trying to integrate the login and authentication with passport.

The `auth/token` giving me the `Bearer token`. But how can I add the authentication middleware in the dashboard redirection after login?

I tried adding `access_token` key in cookie with the token value. And added

```
Passport::cookie('access_token');
```

in `AuthServiceProvider.php` `boot()` function. But still I am getting the error

```
{"status":"error","data":{"message":"Unauthorized"}}
```

Is it possible to implement my idea? If so please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have understood you correctly, but the access token should be placed in the headers not as cookie:

```
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Comment: Yeah. I need to do that. In the case of API validation, the authentication is working perfectly. But for web, when a redirection occur, the header setting will not work. So that's why I got a doubt that will it work for web.